# How can I float a specific field to the right of another field

Tags: views, entities, nodes, theming

For example, I have one field in my content type that is a boolean value of "Is this employee certified" next to this field I'd like a Pop-up Date that shows the expiration field. I've created both fields for my content type but I have not seen anything in the CSS that allows my to float or align fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Can I do this with Views? Or with CSS? Thank you

Comment: Are you mean you want to show the two field beside each other?

Comment: Yes, two different field types aligned next to each other.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [Token Field](http://drupal.org/project/token_field) Or [computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) but the easier way it's to use token field.

You should create a token field then use replacement patterns (each field of your content type has a replacement pattern to print it's value) for example:

I have integer field (field_int), it's replacement pattern should be [node:field_int].

With that you can print the fields between each other.

Comment: Did you mean to answer this question? It looks like might have tried to answer a different one, this isn't what the OP is asking for :)

Comment: but it's alternative solution for what he need.

Comment: Oh right I see what you were going for there. Both of those modules would be a massive amount of overhead to add to solve a simple styling problem though, far better to use `float:left`/`float:right` IMO

Answer (score 1):

You can just use CSS for this. You will need to find the specific element ID or class for the containing element (div for example) for each of the fields (you can find this out using Firebug with Firefox), then create a CSS rule for each of those elements such as:

```
#field1 {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
}

#field2 {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
}
```

You will probably need to then use the CSS rule `clear:left;` for the field or element that follows after them.